# Does a British citizen need an airport transit visa for layovers in Paris en route to the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, uk-citizens

I am flying from the UK, connecting in Paris/CDG for an international flight to the US: Newark NJ. From there, I fly to Savannah, Georgia and on to Lexington, Kentucky.

[image]

I am a British citizen. Do I need a visa for the CDG connection?

Comment: Over 29 hours to go less than 4,000 miles? Wow!

Comment: Can you please copy the information out of the picture into the question itself?

Comment: As long as the UK remains in the EU, you have a legal right to enter any EU country without a visa, not to mention transit through.  After the UK leaves the EU, it's anyone's guess at this point, though the chance that British citizens will require airport transit visas is essentially nil.  It's also very unlikely that they will require short stay visas.

Answer (score 7):

As has already been said, you're not going to need a visa (although you will need to pre-register through ESTA) - but whatever you do, do NOT book this itinerary.

The problem with some online booking engines is that they will put multiple flights together without knowing the implications of doing so. In this case it has given you 2 legs on Allegiant airlines - Newark to Savannah, and Savannah to Lexington with a one hour connection between them. EVEN ALLEGIANT THEMSELVES WILL NOT SELL YOU THIS CONNECTION. It is, very simply, not possible.

Allegiant is a low-cost carrier, and they do NOT offer "connecting" flights. Thus these two flights are considered two individual, single-segment flights. After you get off the plane in Savannah you will need to collect your bags, then proceed to the check-in counter to check in for your second flight, pay (again) their checked baggage fees, and then get through security to your plane. All within (less than) 1 hour.

If (when!) you miss your connection, Allegiant will not offer any assistance - as they don't sell connecting flights!

If you have no checked bags this MIGHT be possible (if only because it's likely the same plane flying both flights), but again if anything goes wrong then you will be on your own.

Comment: Kiwi.com offers these kind of connections (also Ryanair or Wizz connections for example) and you're covered by *their* insurance if you miss a connection. So if something goes wrong, you don't go to the check-in desk AFAIK, but call Kiwi

Comment: @Coke It's still a fairly absurd connection, with checked bags anyway, and insurance won't magically get you to Lexington. If you miss that flight, it doesn't look like you'll find any other direct flights that day; you'll be needing a last-minute ticket on another airline, which could involve going through Charlotte or even back to New York and possibly an overnight stay.

Comment: Absolutely call Kiwi if there's a problem, but the [terms](https://www.kiwi.com/us/pages/content/legal) of their guarantee seem to give them the arbitrary option to actually honor it or not, with things like letting them make partial payment if there's a "a disproportionate price difference between the potential alternative transportation and the original price for the unused Flights," a maximum of €100 for bus/train/taxi alternatives, and hotel rooms and alternate transport are "solely at Our discretion." This reads more as a vague desire to help rather than an actual guarantee.

Answer (score 5):

You're flying from the UK, connecting in Paris/CDG for your international flight to the US/Newark NJ. From there, you're going to Savannah, Georgia and on to Lexington, Kentucky.

As an EU citizen, you don't need a visa, transit or otherwise, to connect in Paris. If you already have your ESTA for the US (or visa, as appropriate), you clear customs and immigration on arrival at the airport in Newark (EWR), entering the United States, and go to take your domestic flights.

Comment: Hey, Giorgio. Could I ask you to be a bit more careful with your edits? Your [edit to this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/108630/revisions) has caused a lot of confusion because your new title claimed the asker had multiple rejected visa applications. Actually, they only had one rejected visa application, but wanted to use the visa to take an exam that they've failed multiple times.